# Is the API method catalogCategoryAssignedProducts usable anymore?

Tags: magento-1.8, api, soap

I am calling [`catalogCategoryAssignedProducts`](http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/catalog/catalogCategory/catalog_category.assignedProducts.html) to retrieve the products that belong to a certain category ID however am facing the following error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [2] Access denied. in /home/magento/www/test.php:25 Stack trace: #0 /home/magento/www/test.php(25): SoapClient->__call('catalogCategory...', Array) #1 /home/magento/www/test.php(25): SoapClient->catalogCategoryAssignedProducts(Object(stdClass)) #2 {main} thrown in /home/magento/www/test.php on line 25
```

The code I am running is:

`$result = $proxy->catalogCategoryAssignedProducts((object)array('sessionId' => $sessionId->result, 'categoryId' => '8'));`

After searching around for a little bit, I read on the Magento forum that this method does not work since 1.4 - is it true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method is still available in 1.8 and 1.9.
Take a look at the [WSDL for 1.9](http://demo.magentocommerce.com/api/v2_soap/?wsdl).  There is an operation called `catalogCategoryAssignedProducts`.